# How to increase video and image upload speed React Native

Tags: react-native, video, expo

I have an app built with Expo & React Native.  I have a feed that has videos and images and because of that I also have the need for users to upload images/videos to my AWS S3 bucket.

As of now I have everything working but for videos especially with a max of 45 second videos can take a little time especially if network is not too strong.  Currently I just take the entire file and upload it directly from hardware file path.  Again this works, but isn't very performant.

How can I go about increasing speed of upload for videos and images in general?

Answer (score 1):

```
 putFileInS3 () {
    RNFetchBlob.fetch('PUT', link,
      {
        'Content-Type': undefined
      },
      RNFetchBlob.wrap(Platform.OS === "android" ? this.state.fileURI :
        this.state.fileURI.replace("file://", "")))
      .then((resp) => {
        this.onImageUploadSuccess(resp)
      }).catch((err) => {
        this.onUploadFailure(err)
      })
  }
```

I would suggest to use https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob .

[COMPARISION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vxuV.png)